Evaluate:$\int^1_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}\ln(1-x)}{1+x^3} dx$
How can this integration be evaluated?

$$I=\int^1_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}\ln(1-x)}{1+x^3} dx$$

This is what I found.
\begin{align*}I&=\int^1_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}\ln(1-x)}{1+x^3} dx\overset{t^2=x^3}{=} \int^1_0 \frac{t^{1/3}\ln(1-t^{2/3})}{1+t^2}\frac{2}{3}t^{-1/3}dt\\ &= \frac{2}{3}\int^1_0 \frac{\ln(1-t^{2/3})}{1+t^2}dt=!!!\end{align*}
In book spacial function by :Yury A. Brychkov P132
$$I=-\frac{2}{9}\textbf{G} -\frac{\pi}{6}\ln(2)$$
$\textbf{G}$:Catalan number

any reason to believe it has a nice closed form?

@SineoftheTime Is the question a source book special function by yury

What is $\textbf{G} $?

$\textbf{G}:Catalan Number$

\begin{align}
I=& \int^1_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}\ln(1-x)}{1+x^3} dx
\overset{x\to x^2}=\int_0^1\frac{2x^2\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^6}dx\\
=&\int_0^1\frac{2x^2\ln x}{1+x^6}dx+\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x^2)\ln \frac{1-x^2}x}{1-x^2+x^4}-\frac{\ln\frac{1-x^2}x}{x^2+1}\ dx\\
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\frac{1-x^2}x}{x^2+1}\ dx\overset{x\to \frac{1-x}{1+x}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln2}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi4 \ln2\\
& \int_0^1 \frac{(1+x^2)\ln \frac{1-x^2}x}{1-x^2+x^4}dx\overset{t= \frac{1-x^2}x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt=0\\
 & \int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln x}{1+x^6}dx
\overset{x^3\to x}=\frac19\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} dx= -\frac19G
\end{align}
Thus
$$I
=-\frac29G-\frac\pi6\ln2
$$

Nice Solution  +1)

Start with $x→x^2$ and use partial fractions
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{2x^2\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^6}dx$$$$=-\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1\left(\frac{-x^{-2}-1}{(x^{-1}-x)^2+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)\ln(1-x^2)dx$$
Note that $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}=\frac{x^{-2}+1}{(x^{-1}-x)^2+1}$$ and continue
$$$$
$$I=-\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{-x^{-2}-1}{(x^{-1}-x)^2+1}\ln(x^{-1}-x)dx+\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\ln(x)dx-\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$$$$=2(J+K-L)/3$$
K is easily evaluated using either a series expansion for $\frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}$ or the beta function's derivative. L is well known so it will be skipped.
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{-x^{-2}-1}{(x^{-1}-x)^2+1}\ln(x^{-1}-x)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx=0$$
$$K=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\ln(x)dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^6+1}\ln(x)dx$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^1x^{6n}(x^2+1)^2\ln x\space dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{(6n+5)^2}+\frac{2}{(6n+3)^2}+\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}\right)$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(12n+11)^2}+\frac{2}{(12n+9)^2}+\frac{1}{(12n+7)^2}-\frac{1}{(12n+5)^2}-\frac{2}{(12n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{(12n+1)^2}\right)$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(12n+11)^2}+\frac{1}{(12n+7)^2}+\frac{1}{(12n+3)^2}\right)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(12n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(12n+5)^2}+\frac{1}{(12n+9)^2}\right)-3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(12n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{(12n+9)^2}\right)$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\right)$$$$=-\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}\right)=-\frac{4}{3}G$$
Finally
$$I=\frac{2}{3}\left(-\frac{4}{3}G+G-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2\right)=-\frac{2}{9}G-\frac{\pi\ln2}{6}$$
